Variable not updating after input
I'm trying to figure out why in the buildInput _isInputEmpty ? Colors.grey : Colors.black doesn't change when I input or clear the text field?
I have to out of the modalSheet and back in to see any changes.
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isInputEmpty = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchStreamingLinks();
    getComments();
    myController.addListener(_handleTextChange);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _handleTextChange() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _isInputEmpty = myController.text.isEmpty;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.removeListener(_handleTextChange);
    myController.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController1.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, AppState>(
      converter: (store) => store.state,
      builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                buildVideoPlayerWidget(context),
                buildSwitchButtons(),
                const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SizedBox(height: 20),
                ),
                buildConcertHeader(context),
                const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SizedBox(height: 15),
                ),
                buildArtistRow(context),
                const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SizedBox(height: 18),
                ),
                buildDescription(context, state),
                const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: SizedBox(height: 10),
                ),
                if (state.concertComments.isNotEmpty)
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: buildPaddedWidget(
                      context,
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => showDraggableSheet(context),
                        child: Container(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8, right: 8),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                          child: ConcertChatWidget(
                            showLike: false,
                            handleCommentLike: () => toggleLikeComment(
                                state.concertComments[0].commentId),
                            comment: ConcertComment(
                              commentId: state.concertComments[0].commentId,
                              userName: state.concertComments[0].userName,
                              userImage: state.concertComments[0].userImage,
                              comment: state.concertComments[0].comment,
                              likes: state.concertComments[0].likes,
                              liked: state.concertComments[0].liked,
                              createdAt: state.concertComments[0].createdAt,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                if (state.concertComments.isEmpty)
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => showDraggableSheet(context),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Be the first to comment',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                buildBottomSection(context),
              ],
            ),
            if (_isPopupVisible) buildPopUp(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showDraggableSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true, // Allows the sheet to expand with the keyboard
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (context) => StoreConnector<AppState, AppState>(
        converter: (store) => store.state,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              initialChildSize: 0.3,
              minChildSize: 0.2,
              maxChildSize: 0.5,
              expand: false,
              builder: (context, scrollController) {
                // Add listener to detect end of scroll
                scrollController.addListener(() {
                  if (scrollController.position.atEdge) {
                    if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
                        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                      print("Reached the end of the scroll");
                    }
                  }
                });

                return Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: kBackgroundColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                      top: Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: SafeArea(
                    child: Column(
                      // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // Drag indicator
                        Container(
                          width: 40,
                          height: 4,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 17,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Comments',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        // Scrollable content
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            controller: scrollController,
                            itemCount: state.concertComments.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: ConcertChatWidget(
                                  comment: state.concertComments[index],
                                  handleCommentLike: () => toggleLikeComment(
                                    state.concertComments[index].commentId,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        if (state.isLoading) const LinearLoader(),
                        Divider(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.15)),

                        // Fixed input box at bottom
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: buildInput(context),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildInput(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: height * .043,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: kBackgroundColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextInput(
                    keyBoardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    controller: myController,
                    onTapOutside: false,
                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                    // onChanged: (text) {
                    //   print('TextInput TEXT: $text');
                    //   setState(() {
                    //     _isInputEmpty = text.isEmpty;
                    //   });
                    // },
                    onFocus: () {
                      setState(() {
                        inputFocus = true;
                      });
                    },
                    hintText: "Add a comment",
                  ),
                ),
                // Spacer(),
                SizedBox(
                  width: width * 0.03,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    String text = myController.text.trimRight();
                    print('GestureDetector TEXT: $text');
                    if (text.isEmpty) {
                      return;
                    }
                    myController.text = '';
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: height * .043,
                    width: 35,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: myController.text.isEmpty
                          ? const Color(0XFF333333)
                          : Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.send,
                        color: _isInputEmpty ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // Text('Send $isEmpty'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }



Your building code is massive and involves multiple builders, function calls, and context borders, any of which could be causing the issue. My first suggestion would be to break this build code up into reusable widget classes.

Thanks @Abion47, made the build method slightly cleaner

Your super.initState() should always be the first step of your override.  You have correctly placed super.dispose() last as it belongs.

I suggest to clear irrelevant codes and ask a specific question. Then, if your view and its logic is complicated use other alternatives for state management like bloc, etc. Or extract your TextInput as Stateful widget and handle its state there.

I used ValueNotifier if I wanted to avoid the variable being changed from another widget rebuild. It happens when there's another event that triggers this behavior. So, consider using ValueNotifier instead of a simple bool declared variable. You can avoid being affected by your widget rebuild if you find out where it came from and include a corresponding handler in your code.

I think the issue you're facing is likely due to the setState() is not triggered properly. This can happen if the listener for the TextEditingController is not calling properly or if the state isn't being managed correctly for this widget.
Solution:

Verify that the Listener Works Correctly:

void _handleTextChange() {
 print("Text is changing: ${myController.text}");  // Debugging line
 if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
  _isInputEmpty = myController.text.isEmpty;
  });
 }
}


Verify that Modal Sheet Rebuilds:

Since the modal sheet is a separate part of the widget tree, you might need to ensure that it triggers a rebuild when the text changes. i.e.
Widget buildInput(BuildContext context) {
     double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
     double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

     return Row(
       children: [
         Expanded(
           child: Container(
             height: height * .043,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               color: kBackgroundColor,
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
             ),
             child: Row(
               children: [
                 Expanded(
                   child: TextInput(
                     controller: myController,
                     onTapOutside: false,
                     focusNode: _focusNode,
                     onFocus: () {
                       setState(() {
                         inputFocus = true;
                       });
                     },
                     hintText: "Add a comment",
                   ),
                 ),
                 SizedBox(width: width * 0.03),
                 GestureDetector(
                   onTap: () {
                     String text = myController.text.trimRight();
                     if (text.isEmpty) {
                       return;
                     }
                     myController.text = '';
                   },
                   child: Container(
                     height: height * .043,
                     width: 35,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       color: _isInputEmpty
                           ? const Color(0XFF333333)
                           : Colors.white,
                       borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                     ),
                     child: Center(
                       child: Icon(
                         Icons.send,
                         color: _isInputEmpty ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     );
   }


You can user 'ValueNotifier' or 'Stream' to Handle Input State:

   ValueNotifier<bool> isInputEmptyNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);

   void _handleTextChange() {
     isInputEmptyNotifier.value = myController.text.isEmpty;
   }

In the 'buildInput' widget, use 'ValueListenableBuilder' to rebuild when '_isInputEmpty' changes:
Widget buildInput(BuildContext context) {
     return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
       valueListenable: isInputEmptyNotifier,
       builder: (context, isEmpty, child) {
         return Row(
           children: [
             Expanded(
               child: Container(
                 height: 40,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: kBackgroundColor,
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                 ),
                 child: Row(
                   children: [
                     Expanded(
                       child: TextInput(
                         controller: myController,
                         onTapOutside: false,
                         focusNode: _focusNode,
                         onFocus: () {
                           setState(() {
                             inputFocus = true;
                           });
                         },
                         hintText: "Add a comment",
                       ),
                     ),
                     SizedBox(width: 10),
                     GestureDetector(
                       onTap: () {
                         String text = myController.text.trimRight();
                         if (text.isEmpty) return;
                         myController.text = '';
                       },
                       child: Container(
                         height: 40,
                         width: 35,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           color: isEmpty ? Color(0XFF333333) : Colors.white,
                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                         ),
                         child: Center(
                           child: Icon(
                             Icons.send,
                             color: isEmpty ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ],
         );
       },
     );
   }


Rebuild Modal Sheet Input Section on Text Changes:

Sometimes, widgets inside the modal sheet need manual triggers to rebuild. You can wrap the entire input section inside a StatefulWidget that rebuilds on text changes.

Thanks @Furqan Sheikh, it wrapping it in a ValueListenableBuilder worked like charm. I will do more research so I can understand how they work a bit better. Thanks again champ!!
